# sending email using django

Tags: django, email, django-views

In my project,an email id field is available.

I am collecting the authors email id and while updating the details in database,an email should send to that particular email id,saying that book name is updated.

My views.py is

def addbook(request):

```
log.debug("test....")

form = BookForm

if request.POST:
    form = BookForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        send_mail(cd['book_name'],cd['author_name'],cd.get(''),['to@example.com'],)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/index/')
return render_to_response('addbook.html',{ 'form':form },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am using this send_mail() method to perform that but it is not working as i expected.

models.py is

class Book(models.Model):

```
book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
email = models.EmailField()
bookref = models.CharField(max_length=10)
class Meta:
    db_table = u'Book'

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%d %s %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name,self.email,self.bookref)
```

forms.py

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):

    log.debug("test....")

    class Meta:
        model = Book

        fields=['book_id','book_name','author_name','publisher_name','email','bookref']
```

An mail should send to the email id mentioned in the email field.

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT`, `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` in your `settings.py`? Also try printing `cd['book_name']`, `cd['author_name']` and `cd.get('')` and make sure that you are getting appropriate values.

Comment: "not working as expected" - how _does_ it work?

Comment: I am getting the values,but it is sending the mail to the hard-coded email id.I need to send to the email id captured in the field.any help accepted

Comment: @user2086641 Simple. Pass the email id captured from the field instead of hard-coding it. Make your question little clear to help you better.

Comment: Sir,an email should send to the email id whatever we are saving in the database,i.e while clicking submit button the book details everything get saved in database.meanwhile an mail should send to the captured email id also.I think this may clear.Any error in doing the same in the above code please notify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your email'
```

**views.py**

```
if request.POST:
    form = BookForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data

        email_to = cd['email']
        subject = "{0} Update".format(
            cd['book_name'])
        message = "Author: {0}\n\n Your book name is updated".format(
            cd['author_name'])
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,[email_to,])

        form.save()
        return redirect('/index/')
```

Comment: In settings.py,in which segment i should edit.My doubt is wheather i should do it in logging configuration.

Comment: you don't have to edit something just add the settings for email

Comment: I am getting an error"global name 'settings' is not defined" it is pointing to send_mail() line.Any header file to import or what file to import please help me

Comment: define settings in your view. Insert in the head of the view `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: @Private thank you I never notice that I put template instead of view :)